# XNA sprite scaling

Tags: xna

When I'm using the `SpriteBatch.Draw()` method I can get vertical or horizontal scaling. For example:

```
new Vector2(1.0f, 2.0f)
```

it means that my sprite will expand the Y-axis. How can I get it to diagonally expand (for example 45 or 70 degrees)?

**(Update from comments)**

I have circle sprite and this picture contains shadows and glare, I need to stretch this circle (make ellipse) and rotate it, but I want the shadow does not change its position into ellipse. Rotation and scaling change every frame.

This picture from World Of Goo game:

[image: Picture from World Of Goo game]

Comment: When you say 'diagonal,' do you mean on stretching on a rotated sprite?

Comment: Yes, exactly. sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First scale it horizontally and then vertically. If it is 45 degrees, you will scale the same in both directions, if its another angle, you can compute the scales using simple sin/cos functions.

EDIT:

C# example:

```
float angle = 70; // Direction in degrees
float amount = 1;  // By how many percent (1 = 100 %)
float radAngle = (angle / 180) * Math.PI;
float xratio = (1 + Math.cos(radAngle)) * amount;
float yratio = (1 + Math.sin(radAngle)) * amount;
// Then just make a new Vector2(xratio, yratio)
```

Beware of bugs in that example, I haven't tested it. Wouldn't it also be easier for you to just stretch the sprite using the Vector2 directly?

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(/* Some stuff */, new Vector2(2.0, 3.0), /* some more stuff */);  // Scale 2x in horizontal and 3x in vertical direction
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, but you don't understand me (or I said incorrect). I try to explain this with an example: You have square, and you need to get rhombus with such ungels: 45, 135, 45, 135 degrees. Can you stretch sprite using scaling and without rotation ? thanks in advise and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question. You cannot do that without rotation - you first need to rotate the square by 45 degrees and then resize it. I'll edit the example code when I have more time.

Comment: Thank you, this is not necessary. I realized.

Comment: I can't rotate my sprite because it is more harder than simple square and it contains drawing. Do you have another ideas to do it?

Comment: Why cannot you rotate the sprite? Whatever is inside, it will get rotated. Could you please upload a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That's what i need: I have circle sprite and this picture contains shadows and glare, I need to stretch this circle (make ellipse) and rotate it, but I want the shadow does not change its position into ellipse. rotation and scaling change every frame.

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible without recalculating the shadow - all these transforms work with pixels only and that makes them unsuitable for the task you need. Depending on your application, the visual artifact might be acceptable but it will never be 100% correct.